Port fowarding ROS2 Humble
Good morning, I have a network communication problem D:
I am writing to ask if it would be possible to do port fowarding of ROS2 humble communications.
I will explain my situation in detail:
I have 3 devices: a PC, a Raspberry and a Jetson.
The PC and the Raspberry are connected to the same local network through wifi.
The Raspberry shares its network connection with the Jetson through the eth0 port.
Therefore, the Raspberry creates a subnet with the Jetson.
The problem is that the Jetson, being in a different subnet, cannot see the pc's topics and reverse (of course I put the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID).
I was thinking of port forwarding from raspberry so as to fowarding the ROS2 traffic between the Jetson and the PC, but trying all ways fails :c

